# CMS for Rails 4 + Ember.js

Tags: content-management-system, ember.js, refinerycms, ruby-on-rails-4, locomotivecms

Is there a Rails gem that adds content management functionality to an existing Rails 4 application, which can be used for an Ember.js front-end via RESTful webservices + JSON?

Comment: Rails CMS that come to mind in general: refinery, radiant, locomotive, browsercms. None of these offer support for Rails 4 that I know of and I don't think any of them have a rich front end library like ember/angular/backbone.

Comment: comfortable mexican sofa is another one, and has a note on installation instructions for Rails 4 https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa

Comment: The current status of CMSs for Rails 4: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20618553/7852