# Is there any cms for Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is there any cms for Rails 4 with Ruby 2? Most of popular engines (Refinerycms, Browser CMS) are made for Rails 3.

Answer (score 13):

There is a gem called comfortable mexican sofa which has rails 4 integration. https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa

```
**Installation for Rails 4**

gem 'comfortable_mexican_sofa', '~> 1.9.0'
```

Comment: 1.9.0 is out for Rails 4.

Comment: Could you already give us an experience report about this gem with rails 4 and ruby 2?

Comment: rails 4 and ruby 2 is fully supported.

Answer (score 6):

- [Refinery CMS can be used with Rails 4.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364951/how-to-install-refinery-cms-using-rails-4/20600134#20600134) You can already use the master branch.
- Browser CMS will support Rails 4 in its [next release](https://github.com/browsermedia/browsercms/wiki/Roadmap). The
  changes needed for Rails 4 are already committed to the master
  branch, so you can start using it now.
- Locomotive CMS has set its [milestone](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/issues/milestones) for version 3.0, [Git Issue 746](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/issues/746), this version is expected to be done around February 2014.
- Radiant CMS shows in its commit history that is working on it. The plan is to release in early 2014.

Comment: LocomotiveCMS's SPRING 2014 ROADMAP http://eepurl.com/OMrwf

Comment: Still waiting for Locomotive on Rails 4

Answer (score 5):

[Alchemy CMS](https://github.com/magiclabs/alchemy_cms) runs with Rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 2):

I have a been building a CMS over the last couple of months based on Active Admin. It is Rails 4 / Ruby 2.0 compatible. Granted I am the only one using it and it isn't in gem form yet.. If you're interested check out the github : https://github.com/websitescenes/cms_admin

Comment: Some screen shots would be great!