# How to install Refinery CMS using Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, refinerycms

I previously never had a problem with Refinery. I was refreshing my knowledge by following along to the tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/332-refinery-cms-basics .Then when I created a new app with Refinery CMS, I got this error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    refinerycms (~> 2.1.0) ruby depends on
      actionmailer (< 3.3, >= 3.1.3) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      actionmailer (4.0.0)
```

But should not these things be there by default with the CMS? why would there be errors only now?

Comment: So an edit was suggested here and 3 members approved. But that then changes the context from a troubleshooting question to a "how-to" question. It then confuses my question details and then renders the currently accepted to no longer be the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, my five cents are that Refinery is not yet available for Rails 4:

- [Is there any cms for Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491063/is-there-any-cms-for-rails-4)
- http://refinerycms.com/
- http://refinerycms.com/blog/refinery-cms-210-released

Best, 
Ben.

Answer (score 15):

The latest code supports Rails 4; the gem must be sourced from the master branch, until a release is made.

[Git Issue #2428 - Rails 4 support](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2428)

Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'refinerycms-i18n', github: 'refinery/refinerycms-i18n', branch: 'master'
gem 'refinerycms', github: 'refinery/refinerycms', branch: "master"
# Strong parameters is a new feature not used by Refinery
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

Do a:

```
$ bundle install
```

Create a new Refinery app, the command will be different depending on what you want to do. For that there are [a few guides](http://refinerycms.com/guides) that you can follow. In my case, I added it to [an existing app](http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app) with:

```
$ rails generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation
```

Start your server and go to: `http://localhost:3000/refinery`

Comment: It seems, adding gem 'protected_attributes' giving error: Validation failed: Title can't be blank. And according to https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-news/issues/140 , removing this gem is solution...

Comment: your steps helped me with this! I left out the protected_attributes gem

Comment: How do you modify the generate command to make it use MySQL instead?

Answer (score 2):

Simply initialize the application using:

```
rails new my_new_application -m http://refinerycms.com/t/edge
```

**Behind the scenes:**
This command makes your application use the master branch of refinery, which supports Rails 4.

**Update**
Although the above is the easiest and official way, it didn't totally work for me. I had to manually run the following command after the above one:

```
 rails generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the rails4 branch has been getting a bit of love over the past few days:

https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/tree/rails4

I will try it out and update with how I get on.

Comment: Looks like rails4 is on master branch now, and they are working on rails 4.1: https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/tree/rails-4-1

I just don't know why they haven't released a new gem with Rails 4.0 as they are already working on 4.1

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's try and answer this one. This is the route I went down.

First, I installed the refinerycms gem.

```
gem install refinerycms
```

I then did a:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Then I followed the guide:

```
refinerycms rickrockstar
```

Bundler complained:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "refinerycms-core":
  In Gemfile:
    refinerycms (~> 3.0) ruby depends on
      refinerycms-images (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
        refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) ruby

refinerycms (~> 3.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-images (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
    refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) ruby

refinerycms (~> 3.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-images (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
    refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) ruby

refinerycms (~> 3.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-images (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
    refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) ruby

refinerycms-wymeditor (>= 1.0.6, ~> 1.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-core (>= 3.0.0, ~> 3.0) ruby

refinerycms-acts-as-indexed (>= 1.0.0, ~> 1.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-core (~> 2.1.0) ruby
```

In my gemfile, I changed the following lines:
    gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

```
gem 'refinerycms'
gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed'
gem 'refinerycms-wymeditor'
```

And this solved the issue.

I had to then do a:

```
bundle install
```

Then a:

```
rails generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation
```

I posted an issue on github and got the following answer from the RefineryTeam:

```
 It looks like the culprit was refinerycms-acts-as-indexed version - it should be ~> 2.0.1 to work with Refinery 3.0.0
```

https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/3072

Please also see this [page](http://www.refinerycms.com/download) where things might be running more smoothly than following the guide on Refinery's website. What is to be seen there is similar to Zuhaib Ali's answer above (in a bit more details).

Hope this helps